# Google Http Client Library java: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('G'

Tags: java, json, google-http-client

I am making a HTTP get request, which gives me a JSON response:

```
{ time : 1345111524000
  sub : Test vote
  msg :
  remain : 420
  cur_time : 1345113672856
  ver : 1.2.2
  p_type : 0
  .....
```

I am using [Google HTTP Client Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/)

My implementation

```
static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

public static class PollInfo{
    @Key("time")
    public String time;

    @Key("sub")
    public String sub;

    @Key("msg")
    public String msg;

    .
    .
    }

    public static class PollInfoUrl extends GenericUrl{
       public PollInfoUrl(String encodedUrl) {
         super(encodedUrl);
       }
    }

    public PollInfo getPollInfo()  throws Exception{
     HttpRequestFactory requestFactory =HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(
                     new         HttpRequestInitializer() {
          @Override
          public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            request.setParser(new JsonObjectParser(JSON_FACTORY));
          }
    });
     PollInfoUrl url = new PollInfoUrl("http://**IP**:8000/web1/num1?cmd=en_poll_info&src=src_web&ver=default&deviceToken=DUMMYDEVICETOKEN&ref_id=83f2491d-0b0c-4d1c-8a14-053256cf157a&p_type=0&p_creator=Wp&eid=3&sender=Wp";);
     HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
     PollInfo pollInfo = request.execute().parseAs(PollInfo.class);
     return pollInfo;
}//getPollInfo();
```

I am able to parse other URLs in my project but for this particular case it is giving me exceptions and i would need some guidance to fix it. 
Below is my server exception log

```
[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('Q' (code 81)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@481a98fe; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:393)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
    at hello.common.ui.gwt.server.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Please guide me where i am going wrong. :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you receive seems to be invalid. It's missing quotes and commas.